# In iOS,What sitiuation may result in wild pointer?

Tags: ios

```
Student *stu = [[Student alloc] init];

[stu setAge:10];

[stu release];

[stu setAge:10];
```

At the code ,if stu released,stu become a wild pointer.
But those code only appear below MRC,What may lead to wild pointer below ARC?

Comment: in ARC the object is released if there is no more strong pointer which keeps the object alive when the scope runs out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get dangling pointers with ARC for properties of type `assign` or `unsafe_unretained`, or variables annotated with `__unsafe_unretained`:

```
// declaration
@property(assign) Student *student;

- (void)createStudent {
    Student *x = [Student new];

    self.student = x;
}
```

Since no one else refers to `x`, the property `student`is a dangling pointer after the method execution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer